# VB.Net Version Number for .msi and setup.exe

Tags: vb.net, setup-project

I have a VB.net product that has projects in it. I was able to embed version numbers on binaries that gets built when running source project (project 1)  using assmblyinfo.vb. There is a second project called setup project to packages all binaries built by project 1 in the form of xxx.msi  and setup.exe files. Is there any way i can embed the same version numbers (present in  assemblyinfo.vb) on setup.exe and xxx.msi files? i'm new to vb.net and fighting with this. pls advise.